# Changing Root View Controller to Tab View Controller in core data app (Xcode4)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to making core data iPhone apps. I created a new core data project in Xcode and attempted to add a tab Bar controller as the root view controller then putting the default tableview controller after the navigation controller in this hierarchy:

->Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller -> TableView Controller -> TableView Controller2 ->details controller

I have implemented an app using navigation and tab bar controllers at the same time before, however for this app I need access to managedObjectModel throughout the app.

I have tried messing around with the app delegate such as didFinishLaunchingWithOptions etc.
I'm always getting messages similar to '

> 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>
> reason: '-[UITabBarController
>   topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'

This is the code I am using to access the ManagedObjectContext:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newCoffee;
newCoffee = [NSEntityDescription
              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Coffee"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

And I'm getting this error:

> No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'managedObjectContext'

I just noticed Xcode says its an ARC issue, how do I access mod with ARC enabled?

Comment: Can you post the relevant app delegate code?

Comment: The app delegate code is the default code created when 'use core data' is selected

Answer (score 3):

Well if I understand your question correct, you want to get access to you NSManagedObjectModel, so you can get acces to your stored data. Am I right?

Well first of all, you should import your Appdelegate in the viewController, where you need to save or load data.

Second of all, you should implement this in your viewDidLoad:

```
    self.context = [self context];

    if (self.context == nil) 
    { 
        self.context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }
```

with @property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context, in the headerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass managed object context from controller to controller. Also if you're initializing some view controller with managed object, you can access MOC via `managedObjectContext` property of that object.

Answer (score 0):

When saying Managed Object Model you mean Managed Object Context - right?

In both cases: You can access the context and the model at any time via the delegate of the shared application object like so:

```
[(YourAppDelegateClass *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] managedObjectContext]
```

But you can also just make a property for each view controller and pass the context down the hierarchy.